# ADT won't run after changes to XML

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

This is just a minor issue, but its rather annoying. If I make changes to the Java files, save and try running, ADT rebuilds and loads the project up as it should. When I make changes to XML, save and try running, ADT doesn't do anything. At this point, I cannot run the project until I edit a Java file, save and run again.

Note: The application is running, but with an old build.

Is this a design flaw, or is there some way to change this behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by 'cannot run'?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse and ADT are you running? I'm using the latest bundle (fully updated) from the Android developer site and do not experience this problem.

Comment: @BenJakuben I'm using `Build: v21.0.1-543035`.

Comment: @wtsang02 When I click run, the application won't rebuild and run.

Comment: Adding as a comment rather than an answer because it's sort of both. I've got the same problem, I have the key combo Command-R set to Run, and after editing an XML file and hitting C-R, nothing happens. The XML file won't even save. If I save it first, it still won't run.

What I found is that if I switch to a Java file and then hit C-R, it build and runs just fine. It will save the XML file if need be, and the app builds and runs just as I'd expect. So just running from a Java file selected rather than an XML file works for me.

Comment: @PhilRingsmuth Yeah. That's what I've been doing, now. It's a hassle, but luckily I have two monitors set up, so I edit XML in one and Java in the other, so the switch is pretty easy.